# LinAlgError: SVD did not converge Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to run the below code and get **LinAlgError: SVD did not converge**

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
X = df.ix[:,1:].astype('float')
X = sm.add_constant(X)
Y = df.ix[:,0:1]
model1  = smf.OLS(Y, X).fit()
```

Any advice to solve the problems is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: My data frame does not have NaN values.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).